# How to get values from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing sql query issue.
Following is the table structure

We have table tbllogin where we are maintaining all type of users like user,admin and vendor columns like 
userId(pk), name, email.

we have another table  tbltransaction where we are maintaining transaction of users column like

id(pk)  userId(fk->tbllogin)  vendorId(fk->tbllogin)

I want to show name as userName,name as vendorName ,email as vendorEmail from tbllogin on the basis of userId and vendorId of tbltransaction

Here two columns in tbltransaction referring two same table tbllogin

Please help me to solve this query issue.

I am also attaching images of sample table structure for more clarity
[tbllogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyAfp.png)[tbltransaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOLZq.png)

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. (As formatted text.)

Comment: show what you tried.

Comment: I want name as username, name as vendorName and email as vendorEmail

Comment: I had added two images of tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this??

```
SELECT u.Name as userName, v.Name as vendorName, v.email as vendorEmail
FROM tbltransaction t
LEFT JOIN tbllogin u
ON t.userId = u.userId
LEFT JOIN tbllogin v
ON t.vendorId = v.userId
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 select Id, lu.name as userName, lv.name as vendorName, lv.email as vendorEmail
 from tbltransaction as t
 join tbllogin as lu on (lu.Id = t.userId)
 join tbllogin as lv on (lv.Id = t.vendorId)
```